# prove this inequality for sufficiently large n

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Prove the following inequality for $n \geq 100$

$$\pi\bigg(\frac{\log (n^2+2n)}{\log 2}\bigg) < \pi(2n) - 1.5\pi(n)$$

$\pi(n)$ denotes to prime counting function

Comment: You can use the fact that $\pi(n) \approx \frac{n}{\log n} $, and that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\pi(n)}{n/\log n} = 1$, so it is sufficient for large n.

Comment: I need to prove it for n>=100

Comment: Can you use algebra ?

Comment: yes,you can use